# Why can't this noun phrase take 'the' - #the skiing pole

Tags: definite-articles

I've been pondering why the following (0-a) cannot take the definite article. Please see 1 through 4. It seems as though when accommodated (by my body and the car in these cases below), the total number of objects dictates and decides whether you should use the or a(n). Two seems to license a definite marker. However, 0-a cannot take the. I've been thinking while the legs, toes, and joints are attached to the accommodater, my body, and the doors to the car, the skiing poles are not to the event, and that this may make the difference. What do you think?

- [0-a] I went skiing yesterday and did pretty well, even though **#the** ski
  pole was bent. (**two** poles) (Birner & Ward 1994)
- [1-a] I broke **my** leg. [1-b] I broke **#a** leg.(**two** legs)
- [2-a] I broke **my** toe. [2-b] I broke **a** toe.(**ten** toes)
- [3-a] I hurt **#my** joint. [3-b] I hurt **a** joint.(**dozens** of joints)
- [4-a] The car screeched to a halt, and **the** door opened. [4-b] The car
  screeched to a halt, and **a** door opened.(**four** doors, normally)

In a nutshell, whether or not a definite marker (the definite article, a possessive etc.) can be used for a single object of more than one seems related to the total possible number of the objects accommodated (i.e., if the total number is two you should only use the/my/other definite markers. If roughly four to ten to ..., you could employ both the/my/other definite markers and the indefinite article. If a number of them, you should only use the indefinite article). However, [0-a] doesn't appear to go along the lines.

I am now thinking the phenomenon may only be applied to a situation where the accommodater and the accommodatee are closely associated. The event 'skiing' and the object the 'ski pole' are not close enough. (On the other hand, me and my 'ski pole' are)

Do you think this is it?

Comment: *My* is not a "definite marker". 0a can have *my,* and 0a-3a are all equivalent in that they can have *my* and not *the.* However there **is** a question here about 4, and it does have an answer.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. You mean you can say 'my skiing pole (singular)' in 0a? And what do you mean by 'it does have an answer'?

Comment: @AndrewLeach But possessive determiners *are* considered to confer definiteness on the NPs they occur in.

Comment: I would find _one of my ski poles_ much more natural. Using _the_ makes it sound like a single item of equipment serving all skiers - _even though the ski lift had broken down_. Also, we wouldn't talk about 'hurting a joint' unless it had been previously established what part of the anatomy was in question. _I twisted my ankle_ but possibly _I fell on my knee and the whole joint is swollen_.

Comment: @KateBunting You said you wouldn't talk about 'hurting a joint,' but your example is about '"the" joint'???

Comment: Things you are wearing or carrying (for a sustained period) are treated as extensions of your body. You have to specify the “owner” of the body part and can’t just use *the*. Hence *my* is required in your first example.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Therefore, you're saying 'my ski pole (singular)' would be correct?

Comment: @Sssamy Exactly so!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Much obliged!

Comment: The article makes no difference - we talk about hurting our knee, hip etc, not our joint.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. 'They've stipulated their thesis (a mistaken, but reasonable one).' I'm curious. How mistaken do you think is that? And your latter part refers to one of Birner's later papers? I know their papers are classic but a lot other authors came out with more findings --- for example, on weak definites.

Comment: Actually the term “ski pole” referred to the *single* long pole used by early skiers. Today we use two shorter pieces of equipment called “ski sticks”. That might explain 0-a. (And it’s best not to have beginners use them, anyway.)

Comment: *...even though my ski pole was bent* is just fine. So is *Someone dinged my car door.*

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can say *my arm* and *my leg* but not *my ski pole* in your examples is that arms and legs are body parts, which are an exception to the rule of the definiteness of personal pronouns.

The possessive personal pronouns *my, your, his, her, our, their* usually confer definiteness, implying that there is only one of whatever. For example, if you say

> my cat caught a mouse yesterday,

most people will assume you only have one cat (unless the context shows that you're talking about a specific one of your cats). If you have more than one cat, you say

> one of my cats caught a mouse yesterday.

However, there are exceptions to this rule. One of these exceptions is body parts—if you say

> my knee hurts,

native English speakers will not assume that you are one-legged.

Another exception is relatives. If you say

> my brother's favorite author is George R.R. Martin, but I hate his books,

it doesn't imply that you only have one brother (you might have one, but you might have more).

Comment: If I have three cats and three brothers, I'm just as likely to say "my cat caught a mouse" as to say "my brother likes George R.R. Martin". It would be interesting to see whether there is any empirical data for this.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I expect that the exception for relatives is sometimes extended to pets. But if you have three sweaters, would you say "my sweater has a hole in it" if it wasn't one you were wearing?

Answer (score 0):

> •  [0-a] I went skiing yesterday and did pretty well, even though #the ski pole was bent. (two poles) (Birner & Ward 1994)

As skiing, unless otherwise stated, involves 2 ski poles, and as “the ” has the nuance of “That particular noun of which you are aware or will become aware”, there is an ambiguity set up as the listener is **not** aware of which ski pole was bent and expects that (i) they will be told. (ii) They are aware that two ski poles are usually held.

*I went skiing yesterday and did pretty well, even though the **left** ski pole was bent.* (two poles) is correct as ski pole is defined as “that ski pole that is held in the left hand.”

Also *One of the ski poles was bent.*

> •  [1-a] I broke my leg. [1-b] I broke a leg.(two legs)

Both are correct. A leg = a [random] example of one of the speaker’s leg. Both are correct, neither indicates which leg. The speaker considers this information unimportant as the difference between breaking a right leg and a left leg is generally not important – it is the pain of the experience of a leg being broken that is important.

> •  [2-a] I broke my toe. [2-b] I broke a toe.(ten toes)

As above.

> •  [3-a] I hurt #my joint. [3-b] I hurt a joint.(dozens of joints)

As above.

> •  [4-a] The car screeched to a halt, and the door opened.

In [4-a] *the door opened* the may be cataphoric – the example may be incomplete. It may be explained later, e.g. “and the driver, passenger got out [from the back [off-side]]” or not. The point is that the listener is aware that cars have doors and that is sufficient to license “the”.

> •  [4-b] The car screeched to a halt, and a door opened.(four doors, normally)

A door = a [random] example of one of the car’s doors. The speaker considers the precise door to be unimportant.

Comment: How about 'I was eating it with a fork with the prong bent' instead of 'with a prong'?

Comment: Why is "**my** ski pole" acceptable for (0a), then?

Comment: *Araucaria. Good point, but Greybeard's main argument is surely sound. I suppose 'my ski pole' is not as particularising as 'the ski pole'. We say 'He went skiing yesterday and broke his leg' but not *'He went skiing yesterday and broke the leg'.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. 1. Thank you Edwin. 2. "My" is understood as "one of my" but the full phrase is not required. The listener assumes the speaker has two and one of them was bent: which one is unimportant. Likewise "a ski pole" indicates "one example of my two ski poles"  That said the example sentence is ambiguous, so it is not the best - "bent" can be a passive participle or adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Greybeard How about. #"The nose got broken" versus "My nose got broken"? There seems to be a general rule that when we're referring to a (still embodied) part of a body, or something that that body is wearing or carrying, we usually have to stipulate whose it is. That's why we don't say "I broke the nose" or "I broke the leg" and why "My ski pole was bent" is ok, but " #... the ski pole was bent" is not. No?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and Greybeard See my last couple of comments under Sssamy's question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. *But possessive determiners are considered to confer definiteness on the NPs they occur in.* I see your point but the definiteness seems to me to be possessive rather than definitive - *the* is definite. If you have six cats, "my cat is dead" is useful but not particularly definite. "The cat is dead" is definite but not useful. (I can see contexts in which "My/The nose got broken" would be correct to indicate the owner's nose.)

Comment: @Greybeard  *But possessive determiners are considered to confer definiteness on the NPs they occur in.* <-- That's just a fact about the last sixty years of linguistics, globally. It was just a reply to Andrew Leach's assertion to the OP that "My is not a "definite marker". It's not about what I think, so much. Or at all, in fact!

Comment: @Greybeard You said both forms are correct:  [1-a] I broke my leg. [1-b] I broke a leg.(two legs). Here's what I referred earlier: https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED295463.pdf. Birner says _I broke my arm_ is fine, _I broke an arm_ is questionable. Both body parts are two in total. So it's not the total number that dictates? (I'm a non-native speaker. I can't tell about these subtleties)

Comment: I read Birner's paper but cannot agree that he says it is questionable. A lot may depend on context "It was a bad crash, I was lucky I broke an arm, others died."

Comment: I guess her question mark in 8-b in that paper represents her feeling that 'break an arm' is not so commonly used. I presume it is perhaps used as in 'broke an arm, _**as opposed to**_ others breaking a such-and-such and dying' ??? Sorry, I'm a non-native speaker, and so I may be utterly wrong.

Comment: No one who actually skis would refer to one of their poles as “the pole”, unless they were pointing it out specifically as an individual item. Poles come in pairs, like shoes and boots.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Does "I was doing a jump turn and the pole broke" work for you?

Comment: @Greybeard Good catch. A jump turn is clearly a one-pole manouevre.

Comment: @user205876 Speak for yourself ( ˙ ).